# Index in root, wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, indexing, directory, external

Okay I've googled this for hours...I installed wordpress to a subdirectory as a content management system, but I want my main index.php along with other files to remain in the root.

What .htaccess code or wordpress settings do I need to use so that the main url http://foo.com/index.php doesn't look for the wordpress/index.php (which of course causes the error "Warning: require(./wp-blog-header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/..."

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to come across these [instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)?

In addition to making changes to `.htaccess` (which Wordpress says that it will try to perform), you also need to change `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` inside `index.php` to `require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php')`.

I recommend reviewing and following these instructions if they appear clear to you.

Update:

You need to make these changes (from the instructions):

1. Go to the General panel.
2. In the box for WordPress address (URL): change the address to the
   new location of your main WordPress core files. Example:
   http://example.com/wordpress
3. In the box for Site address (URL): change the address to the root
   directory's URL. Example: http://example.com
4. Click Save Changes. (Do not worry about the error message and do not
   try to see your blog at this point! You will probably get a message
   about file not found.)

Comment: I know my question may not be so clear, however I shouldn't need any wordpress php inside of the index.php file as I won't be linking to any wordpress content from the home page. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Commandrea, you are not using WordPress's `index.php` then why do u care ? I mean in that `index.php` file what code did u use ?

Comment: I can no longer go directly to the url.com/mainindex.php in my root without getting the missing wp header error as for some reason wordpress is still directing the main url to the /wordpress index.php page.